@brooons/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer don't print ARABIC text using printText
I am using @brooons/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer package for thermal printing. When I pass and arabic text to printText package method, it prints it in chines character.
I tried to encode the ARABIC text string and pass the result to the method with adding (encoding :"UTF-8" } in option argumant,but it prints the encode as (/655u5).
Any idea please?
